NextJs error - Argument of type 'object | undefined' is
used firebase for authentication
error is:

Argument of type 'object | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'

  const [User, setUser] = useState(false);
  const [UserData, setUserData] = useState("");
  const signin=async()=>{
    setProgress(10)
    const UserInfo=await signInWithGoogle(); // UserInfo is a json object
    setUser(true)
    setUserData(UserInfo) //error here......
    console.log(UserData);

    setProgress(100)

    
  }
  const signout=async()=>{
    console.log("sign out");
    setProgress(30)
    alert("Press OK to Log Out")
    signOutWithGoogle()
    setProgress(70)
    setUser(false)

    // User?alert("signed out successfully"):""
    setProgress(100)

    
  }


Please get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them like you are now!

well you initiated UserData with "" an emty string then you expected an object, typescript wouldnt like that:

try at first:
const [userData, setUserData] = useState<any>({});



as you expect an object, and accept any type of data

once you know wich type of results you are really getting you can specify exactly and
create a type like: (it depends on what you use in user)
type User { id: string,
            email: string,
            username: string, 
          }



and use it like :
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<User>({
                                                  id:"",
                                                  email:"",
                                                  username:""
                                                 });

and finally use a try catch and a undefined condition before using setUser data:
    try {
        const UserInfo = await signInWithGoogle(); // Assume this returns a User object or undefined
        
        if (UserInfo !== undefined) {
          setUser(true);
          setUserData(UserInfo);
        } else {
          throw new Error("User info is undefined");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch user data", error);
      }

